# How to change what a button does with the click of another button?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button 1 that calls a function findRandomPlaces()
In this function it does a lot of things such as looping through an array, giving back a random place in the array when the button is clicked and more.
The format of the array is

```
places = [["name","description","latitude","longitude"]]


Button 1 = "Find Random Place"
Button 2 = "GO"
```

What I want to do is when that button 1 is clicked a second button(button 2) will appear that would correspond to that random value from button 1. 
For example if button 1 gave us the random place "Home", then the corresponding button 2 would give us directions to "Home", if you click button 1 again and it gives the random location "Work", then button 2 would give directions to work using that specific latitude and longitude.

The problem I have is within findRandomPlaces() due to the random place it gives. I can only put the code in there since it changes with every button click and I don't know how to put the code from within this function into button 2.

Comment: @MQLN I have 2 IBAction func set up from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Declare another variable that saves the random location name/coordinates when Button 1 is clicked.
Then inside Button 2's action you can check that variable to give direction accordingly. 
It would work if both of these are in the same view controller.